# EWS API Get all Delegate email addresses a user can access

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get a list of all emails that a user can access. I have had a look and the GetDelegates() function does it the other way round. Gets all users that have access to a specific account. I want the other way.

After a search i have only found some questions from a few years back with no real answers. Has anyone managed this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try the publicdelgatesbl Active Directory property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563283(v=exchg.80).aspx which should be the back-linked version of the publicdelegates property that holds the forward list. You will need to use LDAP to access Active Directory to get this though

Comment: Unfortunately the service i am using does not allow use of the Active Directory. Thanks anyway